# Retrieve the position of the div excluding specific divs with a class name

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="center">
    <div id="ContentTop" class="tt1">Top Content</div>
    <div id="abc" class="hide">exrt</div>
    <div id="bcd" class="hide">Content exta</div>
    <div id="MidContent" class="tcg">Mid Content</div>
    <div id="dcd" class="hide">Extra Content</div>
    <div id="asd" class="hide">Extra Content</div>
    <div id="ContentBtm" class="hide">Bottom Content</div>
</div>
```

The output i require is the indexOf the div for the classes ContentTop, MidContent and ContentBtm.

For example, If i click on the div MidContent, the output i require is position 2, since it doesn't contain the class hide.

I need the count of the div's as 1,2 and 3 for the div's that doesn't contain the class name "hide"

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not/, http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*get all divs inside center which are not hidden*/
    $(".center").children().not(".hide").each(function(i,e){
      /* If any one of them is clicked, show their index inside center */
      $(this).on("click", function(event){
        alert("I am div number" + (i+1));
      });
    });
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XtPtq/ showing implementation of this code with your html

Answer (score 1):

Try this selector will give you all dive element which are not having the class hide

for click event you can do this

```
$('.center').click(function(e)
{
   var id =  e.target.id;
   $(".center").children(":not(div.hide)").each(function(index){
         if($(this).attr("id") ==  id)
            alert(index);
     });
}
);
```

Comment: also, `index` is the index of the array. `$(this).index()` works here: http://jsfiddle.net/U2x2M/

Comment: The question is edited, and i need the index in Click event `$('.center').click(function(){index(this});`